# Botón toggle para mostrar otro div

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Estoy intentando hacer un menú con una serie de botones y cada botón contiene un div con informacion traida de la base de datos.

El problema es que al mostrarse los botones, si hago click en el primer botón, me muestra el div. Pero si hago click en los otros botones, me muestran el div del primer botón. Y yo necesito que cada botón muestre su div correspondiente.

**Les muestro con unas imagenes y luego el código:**

1) Estos son los distintos botones:

[image]

2) Si hago click en el primero, me abre lo que van a ver a continuación. Lo que yo necesito es que cuando haga click en otro botón distinto al primero, abra su div correspondiente, y no siempre el mismo que contiene al botón CLÁSICO:

[image]

**Acá va el código:**

**HTML + PHP**

```
<div class="container-fluid categoriasMobile">

            <div class="container">

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-xs-12">

                        <div class="col-xs-12">

                            <h2><small><center>¿Qué te gustaría comer?</center></small></h2>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-xs-12" id="categorias">

                            <?php

                                $item = null;
                                $valor = null;

                                $categorias = ControladorProductos::ctrMostrarCategorias($item, $valor);

                                foreach ($categorias as $key => $value) {

                                    echo '<div class="col-xs-6 btnCategoriasMobile">

                                            <button onclick="mostrarSubcategorias()" class="btn btn-default backColor btn-block btnCategoriasMobile">
                                                <a class="pixelCategorias">'.$value["categoria"].'</a>

                                            </button>

                                            <div id="subcatOcultas"';

                                            $item = "id_categoria";

                                            $valor = $value["id"];

                                            $subcategorias = ControladorProductos::ctrMostrarSubCategorias($item, $valor);

                                            foreach ($subcategorias as $key => $value) {

                                                    echo '<li><center><a href="'.$url.$value["ruta"].'" class="pixelSubCategorias">'.$value["subcategoria"].'</a></center></li>';
                                                }   

                                            echo '</div>
                                            </div>';
                                }

                            ?>  

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

</div>
```

**Javascript**:

```
function mostrarSubcategorias() {
  var x = document.getElementById("subcatOcultas");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que comprendo lo que quieres lograr, pero para eso debes de personalizar el `ID` de las etiquetas `<div>` para cada botón:

```
<div id="subcatOcultas"+identificador';
```

Y luego cuando invocas la función `mostrarSubcategorias(identificador);` debes concatenar el identificador con el nombre del `<div>`.

```
function mostrarSubcategorias(identificador) {
  var x = document.getElementById("subcatOcultas"+identificador);
```

Espero sea lo que necesites.

Comment: la etiqueta del div quedaria algo asi, <div id="subcatOcultas"+identificador+"";

Comment: Buena idea! Voy a intentar trayendo los datos de la base de datos filtrando por alguna comuna para poder dividir uno a uno los divs e identificarlos individualmente ! Gracias

Comment: Listo me cuentas los resultados,

Comment: Muchas gracias! Lo he podido resolver gracias a lo que me indicaste. Saludos compañero!

Comment: Perfecto, con mucho gusto!